# Retrieve data from two or more tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I am making a survey-application in winforms that is connected to a MySQL database. Now I want to show the alternatives of a question, and how many answered each question. I have a table for alternatives called `tblAlt` and a table for answers from users called `tblAnswers`.

There are only 5 alternatives for each question. Is there a way to get each alternative, and how many answered each of them with one query?

This is what I made so far, but this is definitely wrong:

```
SELECT tblAlt.altText, Count(tblAnswers.answerID) 
 FROM tblAlt, tblAnswers 
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & " 
  AND tblAnswers.altID = tblAlt.altID
```

Tables involved are:

```
_______________     _______________     ___________  _______________
|_tblUsers____|     |_tblAnswers___|    |_tblAlt__|  |_tblQuestion_|
| userID      |     | answerAltID  |    | altID   |  | questID     |
| username    |     | userID       |    | altText |  | questText   |
|_____________|     |______________|    |_questID_|  |_____________|
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your schema, hope this helps:

```
SELECT
    tblAlt.altText,
    Count(tblAnswers.answerID)
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question and explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

I would like to help, but I need some clarification. Is tblAlt the only table of questions? Or, is it a table of alternate questions for some other questions table? There must be a missing table of questions or questID doesn't really make any sense, right? Also, tblAnswers contains a link to the user, but not which question (or alternative) was answered. So, regardless, if there is another table or not, tblAnswers should probably at least have a field for altID or questID for this to work at all.

Comment: tblAlt is the table for alternatives for user to choose from. It's a multiple-choice survey., and yes, there is a table for questions too. I have updated my schema now. And my mistake: tblAnswers have a link to both user and alternative as you said.